# Is there a single word for when something becomes neglected or forgotten (e.g. a plant dies because the gardener forgets to water it)?

Tags: single-word-requests

What **single word** can we use to describe something that has “died through neglect”? For example, a plant that has died due to the gardener forgetting to water it.

**Note**: I’m *specifically* hoping to apply this word to a *software* program that used to be amazing but sadly is no longer maintained and thus defunct.

Comment: Defunct is perfect for software - if a library is defunct, it's because nobody is maintaining it anymore. Alternately, consider *deprecated*.

Comment: I agree with @talrnu on _deprecated_. It's a standard term for a program or software feature that was intentionally declared to be obsolete, regardless of whether it was still in use. I would say that the software in question has been neglected ever since it was deprecated.

Comment: A thesaurus can help if you are looking for a different word than you already have: [neglected](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/neglected?s=t), [defunct](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/defunct?s=t)

Comment: Why are you looking for a word to mean something "died", when software cannot die? Abandoned software continues working exactly how it always worked. In casual use, the term "bit rot" is used to describe that abandoned software is not just left alone, but actually stops working as time passes, e.g. from the surrounding software environment changing, making its implicit assumptions no longer hold. - http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bit-rot.html although it's not one word, it's more applicable to describe the 'death' bit than forsaken is.

Comment: A software specific term (hence not an answer) is 'abandonware'

Comment: *Deprecated* software is software that someone has **declared** obsolete or faulty. This question pertains to software that is defunct and perhaps obsolete, whether or not anyone has said so.

Comment: @nelsonic: Can you please clarify your intent a bit further? The title of the question seems like asking for synonyms of "neglected", although you emphasized "dead from neglect" part in the question body. Additionally, the plant and the software example are not along the same line. Do you really want to focus on the "dead" part? In my opinion, most of the answers up-voted are synonyms of "neglected". Some of them captures "dead" but not "neglected".

Comment: out of curiosity--which software program are you looking at, specifically?

Comment: You used the example of a plant in the title. Is it an herb? It might have suffered from abandonmint.

Comment: It "died of neglect" (a phrase I've often used for software products, etc).  "Defunct" doesn't convey any sort of reason for it's demise.

Comment: It's not a single word, but "*forgotten in some bottom drawer*" corresponds to the question title, i.e. "something becoming neglected or forgotten".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I actually really like the word **you** used: I would refer to such a software program as *defunct*, especially if it might be resuscitated in the future. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=defunct&oldid=32837180):

> defunct (comparative more defunct, superlative most defunct)
>
> 1. *(now rare) Deceased, dead.*
> 2. No longer in use, inactive.
> 3. (computing) Specifically, of a program: that has terminated but is still shown in the list of processes because the parent process that created it is still running and has not yet reaped it. See also zombie, zombie process.
> 4. *(business) No longer in business or service.*

Comment: I think this is the only word anybody's suggested the properly captures the 'dead' part of 'died from neglect'

Comment: Captures "terminated" thus "dead" but doesn't capture "neglected" part.

Comment: The definition (3) you cite has nothing to do with obsolescence or failure to function; it refers only to _currently being non-active_,  though it is still _listed_ as active

Answer (score 39):

**Abandoned**:

> - carelessly disregarded without consideration  for the consequences.

An  [unsupported](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unsupported) program/software will end up useless because of lack of proper assistance:

> - (Computing) (Of a program, language, or device) not having assistance for the user available from a manufacturer or systems manager.

(ODO)

Comment: This is the right answer for software, as per the OP. There is even the term "Abandonware".

Comment: A work of art is never truly complete. It is simply abandoned by the artist.

Comment: Just because something is abandoned doesn't mean it's dead, but not being worked on is about as close as a software program gets to dying, so I guess this works in that specific case

Comment: @Josh61 I didn't. I didn't upvote either.

Answer (score 37):

***[Forsaken.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forsaken)***

> Completely deserted or helpless; abandoned.

thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 29):

Although the word is often used for buildings and the like, used in a little bit of a metaphorical way I am sure the picture will be clear if you use [**derelict**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/derelict).

> 1 In a very poor condition as a result of disuse and neglect [*ODO*]

I have often seen software (from an architectural perspective) described as a building, and this would fit right in when the building starts to collapse because of poor maintenance.

Comment: This is possibly the closest. How natural a _derelict petunia_ sounds is a different matter; probably it would work better in computing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It may depend on the size of your petunia, I guess. Please note I have no clue about botany.

Comment: Although I wouldn't use derelict for software specifically, I like it for describing an old website that hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: "The derelict petunia still clung to tiny bits of green near its stem, but it was clearly past rescue." A bit poetic, maybe, but understandable.

Answer (score 12):

The specific word for this state, when referring to software, is *abandonware*:

> Abandonware is a product, typically software, ignored by its owner and manufacturer, and for which no product support is available. Although such software is usually still under copyright, the owner may not be tracking or enforcing copyright violations. Abandonware is one case of the general concept of orphan works. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware)

There are lots of communities that care for and try to resurrect or provide new homes for abandonware: https://www.google.ca/search?q=abandonware - especially old abandonware [games](https://www.google.ca/search?q=abandonware%20games).

Comment: I wasn't even sure if it was a real word, but this was the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 10):

In the specific context of software projects, those which lose their maintainer are usually called either *[abandoned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abandoned)* or *[orphaned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orphaned).*

Quoting the wiktionary:

> abandoned
>
> 2. No longer maintained by its former owners, residents or caretakers; forsaken, deserted.

> orphaned
>
> 1. Abandoned
>
>    > I found an orphaned project, half-completed before its author quit, and decided to finish it.

Answer (score 6):

*Withered*.  This can be used for a plant that is deficient of water or for an arm that doesn't have enough muscle, whether due to old age or a medical condition.

Comment: And by analogy can be used for some other forms of neglect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple term,'disuse'.

As: The garden fell into disuse and became overgrown.

Other terms like 'desuetude' or 'abandoned' or'forsaken' may be tried.

Yet another term, 'dilapidated'(meaning *fallen into a state of deterioration, especially through neglect*) may suit the purpose. It has synonyms like rundown, tumbledown,unkempt, bedraggled etc.

Answer (score 3):

*Forlorn*

> 1. miserable, wretched, or cheerless; desolate
> 2. deserted; forsaken
> 3. (foll by: of) destitute; bereft: forlorn of hope.
> 4. desperate: the last forlorn attempt.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forlorn

*Note: there might also be an idea of sadness because of this status.*

Answer (score 2):

*Dilapidated*

> Dilapidated :  decayed, deteriorated, or fallen into partial ruin
>   especially through neglect or misuse 
>   *Merriam-Webster*

It's a 90% fit in the plant case (because the plant's already dead), but exactly right for every other use.

Answer (score 1):

## Deprecated

> It's a standard term for a program or software feature that was intentionally declared to be obsolete, regardless of whether it was still in use. I would say that the software in question has been neglected ever since it was deprecated.

(taken from the comments by [talrnu](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256227/is-there-a-single-word-for-when-something-becomes-neglected-or-forgotten-e-g-a#comment560965_256227) and [recognizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256227/is-there-a-single-word-for-when-something-becomes-neglected-or-forgotten-e-g-a#comment561009_256227); certainly deserves to be an answer)

Comment: I believe there is a misconception in the programming world that *deprecated* is synonymous with *obsolete*. To *deprecate* something is to express disapproval of it; thus, a deprecated feature is one that is no longer considered appropriate to use. It really doesn't make any sense to say that a flower has been deprecated.

Comment: @Théophile the OP did specifically mention that this is for a software project though, so I thnk the answer has merit. The question is whether the project was intentionally abandonded.

Comment: @dwjohnston Fair enough, but even so, *deprecated* doesn't refer to something that has died from neglect. "It is strongly recommended that you not use this" is different from "no one cares about this anymore".

Answer (score 1):

*Atrophy*

> To gradually decline in effectiveness or vigor due to underuse or neglect

Example:  *WordPerfect was wonderful program before it atrophied.*

Answer (score 1):

In French there is *dépérir* that describes this exact nuance.
French are pretty melancolic I guess, to have a word that describes this.

Mostly it is used in reflexive form, *se dépérir de* (dying from the neglect of something or someone in particular).

So if you're not afraid of gallicism you could try *deperish*.

Answer (score 0):

**Languished**

2. suffer from being forced to remain in an unpleasant place or situation.
   "he has been languishing in jail since 1974"
   synonyms:   waste away, rot, be abandoned, be neglected, be forgotten, suffer, experience hardship
   "the general is now languishing in prison"

Comment: I think we're looking for an adjective

Answer (score 0):

My choice for the best one-word term would simply be: **OUTDATED**. Neglect is the "lack of attention/maintenance." So, just as the forgotten house plant may expire from lack of being watered, a software program may become obsolete due to the lack of updating. Hence, without maintenance it is replaced by newer programs. It becomes outdated.
Of course, this is not in reference to the (plant) example given, but to the *actual* question.

Answer (score 0):

software rot

(programming)   The tendency of software that has not been used in a while to fail; such failure may be semi-humorously ascribed to bit rot. More commonly, "software rot" strikes when a program's assumptions become out of date. If the design was insufficiently robust, this may cause it to fail in mysterious ways.

http://foldoc.org/software%20rot

Answer (score 0):

Put in an oubliette perhaps? An oubliette was a place where you imprisoned people who you wished to forget about. You just dropped them in and left, although in actuality they were often fed and watered pending ransom. https://thebrokenpiecesofme.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/oubliette-new-word-for-the-day/

Answer (score -1):

Legally speaking, it's

**[gross negligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_negligence)**

> Gross negligence is a legal concept which means serious carelessness. Negligence is the opposite of diligence, or being careful. The standard of ordinary negligence is what conduct deviates from the proverbial "reasonable person." By analogy, if somebody has been grossly negligent, that means they have fallen so far below the ordinary standard of care that one can expect, to warrant the label of being "gross." (Wikipedia)

---

You can also say that it's **[criminal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/criminal)** (negligence)

> *informal* (Of an action or situation) deplorable and shocking:

As in: *"It's criminal (negligence) that they stopped supporting that software"*

**EDIT: Oh, I see you want a word to describe the dead plant, not the process... In that case, The software is grossly/criminally neglected**

Comment: "Gross negligence" and "criminal" to not water a plant? Wow... you must be a real plant lover.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a single word that captures "died from neglect". Most of the answers till now capture the "neglected" part but not "died from neglect". *Wither* came close but still no cigar. Although, there is an idiom based on *wither* that exactly fits:

***wither on the vine*** (also *die on the vine*)

> *Fig.* [for someone or something] to be ignored or neglected and thereby be wasted.
>
> <sub>*McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.*</sub>
>
> ---
>
> if something withers on the vine, it is destroyed very gradually, usually because no one does anything to help or support it
>
> <sub>*Cambridge Idioms Dictionary*</sub>

It can be used in software-related contexts also. Here is an excerpt from the book *Software Project Survival Guide* by Steve McConnell (1997):

> About two million people are working on about 300,000 software projects in the United States at this time. Between one third and two thirds of those projects will exceed their schedule and budget targets before they are delivered. Of the most expensive software projects, about half will eventually be canceled for being out of control. Many more are canceled in subtle ways—**they are left to wither on the vine**, or their sponsors simply declare victory and leave the battlefield without any new software to show for their trouble.

Comment: @DCShannon: Did you read the first sentence in my answer? Sometimes single word doesn't cover what OP asks for. I don't understand the down-votes also. I gave details instead of giving the synonyms of "neglected".

Comment: -1, This answer doesn't give a single word adjective as requested, and its assertion that there is no such word is incorrect, as shown by the other answers on this page.

Comment: @DCShannon: That doesn't mean answer is incorrect. That is very personal also. I already gave details. I have no idea why other answers are upvoted. Question is not asking the synonym of "neglected". Also the title of the question was not asking the details in the question body.

Comment: Additionally, some answers captured "dead" part only and not "neglected". I think only derelict came close but still doesn't cover "dead".

Answer (score -1):

**oblivion**

> the state of being forgotten

Answer (score -3):

**Exanimate** may be one word that can fit here.

adjective

1.
inanimate or lifeless.

2.
spiritless; disheartened.

Source : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exanimate

Comment: This does not related to neglect.