# Is there any idiom meaning "died and was forgotten" in English?

Tags: idioms, british-english, offensive-language

Do you know any idiom that would be a counterpart of Russian "помер Никодим, ну и х*й с ним" (Nikodim has died and so be it [and nobody gives a s**t about it])? I came up with a Yoda-like verse "dead and gone cares no one" but I am looking for a real British saying if it exists.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time (or, how can you choose between answers which each deal with only one of your questions?). Question 1 may find [neglected and forgotten](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256227) relevant. I'm going to remove Question 2: please look at the "phrase-request" tag info when you resubmit it.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Please do not post two distinct questions in one. You should make a second question out of the latter part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the colloquial expression is ***dead and buried***. It sort of implies *forgotten*.

We, perhaps, use it less for people, than in a metaphorical sense for things we are glad to see the back of.

*By the time our Prime Minister arrives home from China the Hinckley Point project may be **dead and buried***.

This would mean that the speaker did not approve of the scheme and was hoping that the government would ***knock it on the head*** (another similar metaphor).

This does not, incidentally necessarily reflect my own view of the *Hinckley Point* project.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly *died in obscurity* is closer to the intended meaning, although it is not exactly the same.